# How to put chart in ScrollViewer?

Tags: java, android, teechart

Consider a `LinearLayout` with some UI items and a `TChart`. If I put this layout inside a `ScrollViewer` I would expect scrolling behavior. However, it seems that the chart auto-sizes itself to fit in the available space.

How can I make my layout scrollable when adding a chart to it?

Comment: You need to include your layout file to know for sure.

I suspect you may have your layout width and height attributes set to "fill_parent", which would fill the available space.

Answer (score 0):

You should have you root tag as scrollview like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical">
here will come your all UI items
</LinearLayout>
TChart
</ScrollView>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical">
here will come your all UI items
TChart
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You can also download and embbeded chart widget which is available as an external widget. and is not available as an inbuilt widget in android project.